# Removing a row in firebase RTDB javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to remove a data row in my firebase Realtime Database.  The data structure is as below:

```
-messages
    -uniquekey1
          -name
          -email
          -message
    -uniquekey2
          -name
          -email
          -message
```

I am trying to write code where I can remove specific data as a whole using key to delete whole uniquekey 1 data with unique key

```
 const firebaseConfig = {
        databaseURL: "***"
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const database = firebase.database();

    // send data
    var listRef = database.ref('messages/')
    var newRef = listRef.push()
    newRef.set({
        'name': 'ok',
        'email': '@@@',
        'message': 'hello there'
    })
    // fetch data
    var fetchedData = database.ref('messages/')
    fetchedData.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        var data = snapshot.val()
        for (var key in data) {
            var value = data[key]
            console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))
        }
    })
    //doesnot work
    database.ref('messages/' + 'key').remove()
    //works
    database.ref('messages/-key/' + 'email').remove()
    //works
    database.ref('/').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear which Real Time Database (RTDB) node you want to delete, but the following code will:

1. Create a new node;
2. Print its value via the `onValue()` observer;
3. Delete it with `database.ref("messages/" + newRef.key).remove()`.

   ```
   var listRef = database.ref('messages/')
   var newRef = listRef.push()
   newRef.set({
       'name': 'ok',
       'email': '@@@',
       'message': 'hello there'
   })
   // fetch data
   var fetchedData = database.ref('messages/')
   fetchedData.on('value', (snapshot) => {
       var data = snapshot.val()
       for (var key in data) {
           var value = data[key]
           console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()))
       }
   })

   database.ref("messages/" + newRef.key).remove()
       .then(() => {
           console.log("RTDB node with key " + newRef.key + " was deleted");
       });
   ```

In each of the first two attempts in your question (bottom of your code) you pass a constant value to the `ref()` method. You need to pass the path of the node you want to delete. The last attempt works but it actually deletes the entire set of nodes contained in your RTDB (if the security rules allow it).

Comment: hello sir thanks i appreciate your reply,
i will give key like i will give the key code `abaa438434buerae` like that and it should delete row with that key

Comment: Hey @IllDimension101, in that case you can use the last 4 lines of the code snippet to delete the node - substituting `"abaa438434buerae"` for the `newRef.key` in the answer.